# How was this "smart" editor implemented? (iOS app)

Tags: ios, xcode, text, uitextview

When entering text in the iOS app below ("Connection Practice Daily Journal", which is free, by the way, if you want to try it) ...

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/connection-practice-daily/id1138389671

... the app suggests possible next words based both on

- the letter or letters you have already typed and
- the syntax and meaning of your sentence so far.

For example, below, it suggests "like" or "love" based on the first letter "l" and the fact that "I" was the first word in the sentence.

I wrote to the developer several days ago asking how this was done, but have not heard back.  Is there a library that implements this functionality?

[[image: Connection Practice Daily Journal app [1]]

Comment: this is standard iOS behaviour isnt it? maybe just a flag change on the textfield to make it give suggestions

Comment: This is standard iOS Keyboard behaviour. If you longpress on your keyboard change(Globe/Emoticon), you will get the prediction option